# C# LINQ - Type Arguments Cannot Be Specified From Usage

Tags: c#, linq

I was writing a function to parse an input from a string to get all the integers into a list. However, I got an an error:

The type arguments for method

```
System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Now I have tried to specify them but to not avail.

The logic of the code (using example input of "56#3=45#90") is:

So I am splitting `"56#3=45#90" (on '=')` into a string array of `{"56#3", "45#90"}` to be operated on by Select, which will split `(on '#')` into 
 Enumerable(`IEnumerable(string)`) containing `"{"56", "3"},{"45", "90"}`. Finally, the `SelectMany` is supposed to flatten the structure (and convert to int) into `{56, 3, 45, 90}` which should be able to be converted into a list.

I don't see any reason why there's something wrong with specifying type arguments.

```
// string 'a' contains "<int>#<int>=<int>#<int>" such as "56#3=45#90";
public static IList<int> ParseCKPInput(string a)  
{
        return (a.Split('=')).Select(n => n.Split('#')).SelectMany(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToList();
}
```

I understand this can be done by regex (which I have implemented now); however, I want to improve my understanding of LINQ and figure out what is wrong with my original code. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `.SelectMany(n => Convert.ToInt32(n))` doesn't work is because `n` will be a list, and you can't convert a list to an int.

The query should be :

```
return a.Split('=')
        .Select(n => n.Split('#'))
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))
        .ToList();
```

Or... there is no need to flatten this just pass all the split characters in at once:

```
return a.Split('=', '#')
        .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I ran it and got an error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<string,int>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>, System.Func<string,int>)' and 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<string,int>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>, System.Func<string,int,int>)'"

Comment: And I don't really understand why I can't do the conversion ToInt32 inside the selectMany since it operates no differently than Select except also flattening the structure

Comment: Previous answer was fine, just replace `Select(Convert.ToInt32)` with `Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c))`

Comment: The select many returns a list. obviously you cant convert a list to an int

Comment: Oh, that makes so much sense. Thanks a bunch for all the help!